Best practice in including C functions of R library into a R package for CRAN
We are building a R package for the CRAN that only contains R functions. However, one of these R functions directly calls stats:::C_Cdqrls, which is a built-in C functions of the stats library of R. We do this for performance, as the main function lm() (which call stats:::C_Cdqrls) is much slower, and our algorithm needs to perform millions of linear regressions.
When building the package, the following (legit) warning rises:
❯ checking foreign function calls ... WARNING
  Foreign function calls to a base package:
    .Call(stats:::C_Cdqrls, ...)
  Packages should not make .C/.Call/.External/.Fortran calls to a base
  package. They are not part of the API, for use only by R itself and
  subject to change without notice.

What are the good practises here ? Should we still include a call to this C function into a wrapper, for example:
Outputs <- function() {
  result <- .C("stats:::C_Cdqrls",...)
  return(result)
}

which ultimately does not solve the issue (ie. stats:::C_Cdqrls can possibly change in futures versions of R). Or should we include all dependancies of stats:::C_Cdqrls in the package, which is not easy as stats:::C_Cdqrls calls a large number of other C and header files, but would make the package immune to any futur changes (in this R library)?
Browsing the internet and the following Stack questions:
writing an R pkg that builds an executable during installation
What is the preferred method for sharing compiled C code in an R package and running it from another?
Building R package using RStudio & roxygen2: Include a C function
Including compiled shared C library in R package and calling functions in it from R wrapper functions
Does not help clear this warning.

You are not allowed to do this in a CRAN package. Maybe use RcppArmadillo::fastLm or RcppEigen::fastLm or other alternatives instead.

Base R also includes lm.fit and .lm.fit. The latter is pretty fast, see the test in its help page examples section.

collapse:flm interfaces to 6 different methods of calculating regression coefficients.  See method argument.

Thank you. After some benchmarking, we found that these methods are similar in terms of running time. However, stats:::C_Cdqrls computes much more quantities (meaning that it perfoms more operations in a similar running time), making it more efficient than the other methods.
